# How to validate email address inside md-input in Angular 2

Tags: validation, angular, angular-material

I have this Angular 2 form with `md-input` element inside:

```html
<form  noValidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(resetPasswFg)" [formGroup]="resetPasswFg" style="width:400px;border:1px solid black; ">
  <table style="width:400px;">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <md-input  class="input" mdInput placeholder="Email" type="email" formControlName="email">
          <md-hint class="input_error" *ngIf="resetPasswFg.get('email').hasError('required') && resetPasswFg.get('email').touched">
            Email required
          </md-hint>
        </md-input>
      </td>
    </tr>
<!-- Other elements -->
</form>
```

and this is my validator inside component:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
    this.resetPasswFg = new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.required ])
    })
}
```

Now, if email field is not populator, `md-hint` appear correctly. Now I would that `md-hint` appear also if email `md-input` doesn't contain a well formed email address.
How can I do?

Comment: You can use `Validators.pattern` and apply some regexp.

Comment: Angular 4 has a new built in email validator: https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/d69717cf79c3141cdbd69b538a3aaded55a8f43b

Comment: Why are there two `Validators.required`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use email validator via directive. See [EmailValidator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/EmailValidator-directive.html) class.

> A Directive that adds the email validator to controls marked with the email attribute, via the [NG_VALIDATORS](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NG_VALIDATORS-let.html) binding.

---

```html
<md-input  class="input" mdInput placeholder="Email" type="email" formControlName="email" email>
```

The directive is also available in package [ng2-validators](https://github.com/Nightapes/ng2-validators).

Comment: how i put the condition of wrong validation inside ngIf condition of md-hint?

Comment: `<span *ngIf="email.hasError('normalEmailRule')">Is not a email</span>`, just replace span with md-hint